# Excel how to get if minute time is 4:38 it shows 4.50 and not 4.58

Tags: excel

I am working on an excel formula that gets the overtime hours rendered. Please refer to the image below

[image]

I have the formula to get the rendered overtime hours but if there's some excess minutes it will display it also what I wnt is if the rendered hour is `1:35` it will display as `1.5` not as `1.58`.

And here is the formula that I used

```
=IF(K13="",VALUE(0),IF(F13 = "RD",VALUE(0),VALUE(TEXT( K13 - RIGHTB(F13,7),"h:mm")*24)))
```

I am using microsoft excel 2010

**EDIT**

A clarification from the comments:

If the value is 1.4, it should round off to 1.0. (The goal is to round *down* to a half-hour.)

Comment: Why 1.5? Can you give examples of what output you want for other numbers? E.g. should 1.4 stay 1.4 or round up to 1.5 or down to 1.0?

Comment: Is the checkout time always 3pm, or do you plan on somehow reading that from the schedule range?  If the latter, I would recommend storing the scheduled login and logout times in separate columns.

Comment: @smarx if value is 1.4 it should round off to 1.0. Because the only allowed duration of Overtime hours rendered is hour or half. They will not accept 1.4 or something

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you look at my formula that's why I get the RIGHT of the Schedule collumn to determine what should be the time out of an employee

Comment: @VianOjedaGarcia Probably `TRUNC(x*2)/2`? (Sorry, I don't have Excel to try it myself. `x` should be your existing computation.)

Comment: @smarx it works perfectly. Please pose this as an answer so I can accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting as an answer so it can be accepted:

```
TRUNC(x*2) / 2
```

Comment: Just addition, You can also use INT. According to microsoft INT and TRUNC works the same. Except when using on negative numbers.